# critique on the style and layout of my proof

Tags: proof-writing, article-writing

This is a small proof I wrote up working through the second chapter of Michael Spivak's Calculus. I'm fairly certain that it is correct but it is my first attempt at writing out a "well-formatted" proof and thus I am worried if there are any problems with layout or style.

We are asked to prove the following statement using mathematical induction,
$$1^2+...+n^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}.$$
A quick check convinces us that it holds true for $n=1$ and, as follows, we assume the expression to be true for some $n=k$. Now, we wish to show that
$$1^2+...+k^2+(k+1)^2 = \frac{(k+1)(k+2)(2k+3)}{6},$$
which we do by using our just stated assumption as follows
$$[1^2+...+k^2]+(k+1)^2 = [\frac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}{6}] + (k+1)^2.$$
Then, on the right hand side, we factor out $(k+1)$ and simplify, giving us the expression
$$(k+1)\frac{2k^2+7k+6}{6}.$$

Using, for example, polynomial long division, we can factor out $k+2$ from $2k^2+7k+3$, leaving us with $(k+2)(2k+3)$ and finally
$$\frac{(k+1)(k+2)(2k+3)}{6}. $$ $$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

Comment: Proof is perfect. Though you can add some terms like "base case checking" and let the sum denoted by $S(n)$ to give it fancy look.

Comment: It's correct and readable that's the important bit. A good mathematical writing style develops over time and is difficult to master. It is important that a reader can understand what you are doing and why you are doing it or at least can see that it proves whatever needed to be prove. Good job, this is fine.

Comment: It's just fine.